YAMLException: unacceptable kind of an objext to dump [object Undefined]
I have been struggling with this error for a few hours and was hoping one of you could point out a solution? I am receiving the YAMLException error (title) when trying to deploy my endpoint. My userid is stored in a token. Here are my yaml files:
favorites-add-post.yaml:
Method: POST
Path: /favorites/add
Description: |
  Allows users to add favorite pages to their profile. This inserts a new favorite into the database, which can be queried later through the getFavorites endpoint.  Enhances user experience by allowing quick access to favorite pages.

Integration:
  Uri: https://${opt:authority}/{Version}/favorites/add
  RequestParameters:
    integration.request.path.Version: stageVariables.Version
    integration.request.header.X-API-Path: "'/favorites/add'"

Parameters:
  Authorization: |
    Requires a valid, unexpired JSON web token for authentication.
  Content-Type: |
    Request body must be `application/json`.

RequestModel:
  $schema: "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#"
  type: object
  title: AddFavoriteRequest
  required:
    - favorite
  properties:
    favorite:
      type: string
      description: Identifier of the favorite item to be added.

RequestSamples:
  - {
      "favorite": "Allowances"
    }

Responses:
  "200":
    Description: Returned on success.
    Model:
      $schema: "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#"
      type: object
      properties:
        message:
          type: string
          description: A message indicating the successful addition of a favorite.
        userid:
          type: string
          description: Echoes back the userid for confirmation.
        favorite:
          type: string
          description: Echoes back the favorite added.
    Samples:
      - {
          "message": "Favorite added successfully",
          "userid": "user123",
          "favorite": "Allowances"
        }

  "400":
    Model: StandardErrorModel
    Description: Returned on a bad request, such as missing required fields.
    Samples:
      - { "Message": "Bad Request - Missing required fields" }

  "500":
    Model: StandardErrorModel
    Description: General server error, typically due to database issues or processing errors.
    Samples:
      - { "Message": "Error processing request" }

Please let me know if you see where I went wrong. Thank you for looking.

I double checked yaml files to make sure all objects were defined. From what im seeing, they are.

I logged the error and found out that it is being thrown because of an object called NAME but I am not seeing that anywhere in my YAML, controller, or .json schema files.



My solution was removing a trailing comma in the Samples section of another yaml file.
